# Реализация вектора, неясные моменты - C++

Tags: c++, list, шаблоны-с++, stl, vector

Добрый день, хочу узнать как работают следующие конструкции:
1) Циклический или цепной вызов конструктора. Что именно происходит в этом фрагменте, как вызываются конструкторы?

```
template <typename InputIterator>
vector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) : vector(last - first)
{
    std::copy(first, last, m_first);
}

vector(std::initializer_list<Type> init) : vector(init.begin(), init.end())
{
}
```

Я правильно понимаю, что при вызове первого конструктора вызывается второй, а при вызове второго первый? Как все происходит?

2) Как использовать assign в оператор = ?

```
vector& operator=(const vector& other)
{
    if (this != &other)
        vector(other).swap(*this);
    return *this;
}

template <typename InputIterator>
void assign(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
{
    vector<Type>(first,last).swap(*this);
}
```

3) Не могу правильно сформулировать, но попробую как-то так, в какой момент или откуда берется int в постфиксном операторе ++ -- ? (это уже реализация списка)

```
// префискный инкремент
list_iterator& operator ++ ()
{
    m_node = m_node->next;
    return *this;
}

// постфиксный инкремент
list_iterator operator ++ (int)
{
    list_iterator buf(*this);
    ++(*this);
    return buf;
}

list_iterator operator -- ()
{
    m_node = m_node->prev;
    return *this;
}

list_iterator operator --(int)
{
    list_iterator buf(*this);
    --(*this);
    return buf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Первый - создается вектор заданного размера (конструктор от `size_t`), заполняется алгоритмом `copy`. Второй - использует конструктор, которому передается диапазон.
2. Вопрос не понял.
3. `int` (фиктивный, значение не передается) нужен для того, чтоб компилятор мог отличить префиксный оператор (без этого фиктивного `int`) от постфиксного (с ним).

Comment: 2)     ```if (this != &other) assign(other.begin(), other.end());```